# angularjs , any idea how to include "" in ng-bind=""

Tags: html, angularjs, html-input, ng-bind

any idea how to put>> `phoneNo["phoneno"]` in html input using ng-bind angular??   `phoneNo["phoneno"]` can display if use `{{phoneNo["phoneno"]}}`, but it turn to syntax error when i put

```
<input class="form-control" type="text"  ng-bind="phoneNo["phoneno"]" readonly />
```

Comment: Wouldn't `ng-bind="phoneNo['phoneno']"` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `"phoneNo['phoneno']"` or `'phoneNo["phoneno"]'`.